# AutoFill when user types into a combo box using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm currently working on a project that I need to have a combobox in an excel sheet for. I have the data needed for the combo box inside of a different sheet in the current workbook I am using.

My question is, is there a way to add autofill/autocomplete functionality to the box using VBA?

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub ThirdFloorBox_Initialize()
ThirdFloorBox.Clear
ThirdFloorBox.List = Sheets(8).Range("A3:A37").Value
ThirdFloorBox.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. **FYI:** I'm new to VBA as most of my coding experience comes from the front-end web world.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829823/vba-get-combobox-to-suggest-an-option

Answer (score 0):

Best if you define the range (Serving the list of Thirdfloorbox) in Name Manager and then in the properties window of the box you can add that range as the rowsource.