# Changing selection of ComboBox due to value of textbox nVBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to change the selection of the combo box when a user types in a matching value in textbox how would I go out about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Get Combobox to 'suggest' an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829823/vba-get-combobox-to-suggest-an-option)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your combo box is called "`yourTextBox`", you have to implement the macro **`yourTextBox_Change()`**

```
Private Sub yourTextBox_Change()
    ' Change the value of the ComboBox
End Sub
```

This macro will be called every time a text was entered in the text box.

If you want to modify your combo box only when the text box looses the focus, you can use **`yourTextBox_LostFocus()`**

Comment: hmm basically I want the combo box to equal what I type in the text box if it exists within the combo box list but how can you make the text box equal to the combo box and also check the combo box list?

Comment: Sorry, I validated my comment before I finished to write it and I spent too much time to edit it.
This is my final answer :
you can use `comboitems = yourcombobox.List` to obtain the list of items and hence `yourcombobox.List(i)` for the ith item